# Spring Boot feign exception

Tags: java, xml, api, spring-boot, feign

I am trying to make an API request with application / x-www-form-urlencoded.

Here is my feign client:

```
 @Bean
public YandexDelivery yandexDelivery() {
    return Feign.builder()
            .client(new OkHttpClient())
            .encoder(new FormEncoder())
            .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(YandexDelivery.class))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .target(YandexDelivery.class, "https://delivery.yandex.ru/api/last/searchDeliveryList");

}
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface YandexDelivery {
@RequestLine("POST")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
Delivery getDeliveryVariants(Map<String, ?> request);
```

}

This is how I call:

```
@Autowired
private YandexDelivery yandexDelivery;

@Override
public Delivery getDeliverysType(String cityFrom, String cityTo, Integer clientId, String deliveryType, Integer height, Integer indexCity, Integer length, Integer senderId, Integer weight, Integer width) {
    DeliveryVariantsModel model = new DeliveryVariantsModel(cityFrom, cityTo, clientId, deliveryType, height, indexCity, length, senderId, weight, width);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("secret_key", model.getSecretKey());
    map.put("client_id", model.getClientId().toString());
    map.put("sender_id", model.getSenderId().toString());
    map.put("city_from", model.getCityFrom());
    map.put("city_to", model.getCityTo());
    map.put("weight", model.getWeight().toString());
    map.put("length", model.getLength().toString());
    map.put("width", model.getWidth().toString());
    map.put("height", model.getHeight().toString());
    map.put("delivery_type", model.getDeliveryType());
    map.put("index_city", model.getIndexCity().toString());
    return yandexDelivery.getDeliveryVariants(map);
}
```

And here is my mistake:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: feign.Request$Body
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you leave out the `spring-cloud-starter-feign` in dependency?

Comment: Im add this dependency. this not help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The fix was to set the correct spring cloud dependency fitting to the used Spring boot version. You can find the correct setting at https://start.spring.io/actuator/info
in my case for Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE i had to use spring-cloud.version Greenwich.SR1